# what does the pie symbol mean in macOS finder?

Tags: macos, finder

could someone explain this symbol? The files are on a AFP share which is mounted.[image: macOS Finder screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

The pie symbol indicates that the element is being uploaded or downloaded to/from a server. Those elements may not be available locally.

The grayed part of the pie represents the percentage of data already transmitted so in your case as this part is very narrow it means that for each file the update has just started.

Answer (score 2):

The pie symbol is a progress indicator that indicates the manipulation of a file of some kind. Since you are taking about [Apple Filing Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol) (AFP), you are most likely referring to either:

- Transferring from internal to network
- Copying from network to network

It could also be:

- Transferring from a drive to another drive
- Transferring from network drive
- Copying a file
- Safari (and other) downloading from the internet
- and many more…

As @LouisLac said, this could also be uploading or downloading from iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

The colour of the pie icloud uses is indeed somewhat confusing.

While I was looking at it as my files were synchronising I understand now:

Full black means 100% sync.

And white means the amount left to sync.

[image]

For example right now my drive is around 90% sync. And 10% files are left, waiting for sync on the icloud server and devices.